# Mosquitto prevent duplicate login

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to prevent user from duplicate login.

Currently I use mosquitto with signing different PKI for each client, but even if I turn on off the `allow_annonymous` flag, the user can still connect the mosquitto server without username and password. (So user can duplicate login with one PKI)

Is there a way to ensure PKI can only login in one session? Is set the username/password file can prevent duplicate login? Or other way to disable duplicate login?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to limit the number of connections based on the username (or certificate cn)

Best you could do is ensure that each user uses the same `client_id`, since only on connection is allowed per `client_id` when a second tried to connect it will disconnect the first

Comment: Thanks @hardillb, I just figured out an weird combo solution, use `require_certificate` and `use_identity_as_username` and `use_username_as_clientid` three flag. Since mosquitto cannot login as same client id, the old connection will be closed. That's the closest solution for me now. Do you think there is some bugs here?

Comment: hmm, I'd missed `use_username_as_clientid`. That should work

Comment: Yeah :D. BTW, do you know how to change the duplicate client mechanism? After changed these config, if I have two client use the same PKI, then two client will repeatedly kick out the other. Is there any flag for changing this that the latter connection will fail, not kick out the first one?

Comment: No, there is no way to change that

Comment: Should I create a new question or the above question is ok here?

Comment: Considering the answer, no need for another question